# No keyboard when running Android app on BlackBerry 10 simulator

Tags: android-softkeyboard, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I have my first Android app running on the BB10 Dev Alpha simulator (10.0.10.261) which is running fine, other than the keyboard doesn't appear at all.  My app contains code to show and hide the on-screen keyboard at appropriate times but this isn't working on the BB10 simulator (works fine on Android devices).  Is this a bug with the simulator?  Has anybody else had their Android keyboard show/hide properly on BB10?

Comment: Hi Jonathan I tested on BB 10 Device,It works well,Only issue is with edit field filter,Eventhought it filters,It shows same keyboardCharacters,we need to search and type such as numbers,Incase editfield supports only number.I am searching for workarond or assistance

Comment: Thanks for the response Rakesh.  So are you saying it works well on the actual hardware device but not the simulator?  Unfortunately I don't have an actual device to test with.

Comment: Yes It works fine in device,I never tested in simulator,I loaded directy the android app to BB 10 alpha device with latest OS released on Jan 30 using Eclipse Android Packaging tool,Keyboard pops up No issues,I have specified issue in my qn regarding keyboard in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725876/keyboard-related-issue-porting-android-to-bb-10-application

Comment: In the simulator the keyboard pops up for me automatically when a text field is selected, but it's completely black. Just a flat black window (sometimes gray). Clicking it does nothing. I can drag from the lower-left to show the real keyboard, which pops up on top and works, but it's clipped on the right (no P key). I have no physical device to test with. I'm not sure how I'll have the confidence to release this.

Comment: For information, I've logged this problem on BlackBerry's issue tracking website (Jira).  You can view the issue here : https://www.blackberry.com/jira/browse/BBTEN-889   (you need to login with a BlackBerry ID).  It has been escalated to developers.