# Numeric keyboard not displaying when porting Android app to BB10

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I have an `EditText` field in my application with `inputType="number"`. When selecting the field, the normal keyboard appears; it shows the normal Qwerty keyboard without numbers.

I want the keyboard to display the number keys in the keyboard rather requiring the user to manually switch to enter numbers. Has anyone faced a similar sort of issue? Is there any workaround for this?

I'm running the latest BB10 OS on a Dev Alpha device (released Jan. 30, 2013).

Comment: i was able to find the getaround for EditField which has have password proprty to true,Remove inputtype = number and add android:digits:1234567890,You will able to see the NumericKeypad on top on Keypad,Still not able to find solution for non password edit fields

Comment: I encountered your question on the BB10 support forum; linking it here for completeness: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/How-to-make-the-keyboard-to-show-UI-filter-support-for-BB-10/td-p/2139827