# How to programmatically set the android:password="true" or false

Tags: android, blackberry-10

I am porting my android app to BB 10,there is keypad filtering issue,

[Numeric keyboard not displaying when porting Android app to BB10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725876/keyboard-related-issue-porting-android-to-bb-10-application#comment21424261_14725876)

so as a getaround i am trying to use `password=true` in xml file,after entering the values in `edittext` field ,i should set the `password = false` programmatically from that point onwards

,Is there anyway to achieve this?

as you guys suggested i tried like below code also,but no changes

```
    myNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myNumber);
myNumber .setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());//this one also
myNumber .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);//this two
```

But it does not have much of Change,No filtering happens with this 2 lines of code also

Comment: Have you face ORIENTATION Problem in Blackberry 10. i want to allow only landscape mode. have you any idea?

Comment: i have set orientation in my Manifest file but not work in BB10 Simulator.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586301/set-inputtype-for-an-edittext) link:

```
youredittext.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying for something like this

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```